# How to build the principal SU(2) bundles on surfaces?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, at.algebraic-topology

Is there a way to classify (and build) the principal SU(2) bundles over a given topological surface up to homeomorphism?  In the end, I would like to examine the associated bundle whose fiber is a given irreducible [representation of SU(2)](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/notes10.pdf).  Perhaps this construction appears in the physics literature.

Comment: Principal $G$-bundles are classified up to isomorphisms by homotopy classes of mappings to $BG$ or by elements of a non-abelian cohomology set. I've tried to summarize this here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15224/triviality-of-fibre-bundles/15290#15290

Answer (score 4):

By "surface" you mean a 2-real-dimensional manifold $F$? If so, there is only one principal $SU(2)$ bundle  up to bundle isomorphism, the trivial bundle:  $F\times SU(2)\to F$. This is because the 3 skeleton of $BSU(2)$ is a point. So the associated bundles to any rep $SU(2)\to GL(V)$ are also trivial: $F\times V$.

If by "surface" you mean smooth complex projective variety of complex dimension 2, then there are an integer's worth of bundles (topologically), determined entirely by the second Chern class.

Comment: Although there is only one bundle up to isomorphism, it's wrong to say that it "is" the trivial bundle: there's no canonical isomorphism between a given SU(2) bundle and the trivial bundle, but rather the space of such isomorphisms is a torsor over the group of sections of the trivial bundle.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the statement that the trivial bundle is the only bundle up to bundle isomorphism. But (as everywhere in mathematics) the existence of non-trivial automorphisms implies that there is ambiguity in choosing an identification of your object with a fixed object.

Actually, in this case (SU(2) bundle over a 2-manifold), the group of bundle automorphisms  is path connected, and so any two identifications of your bundle with the trivial bundle are homotopic, so you get a little bit more "canonicalness" than in general.